# collaborative editing in ruby on rails - architectural approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, eventmachine, collaborative

In our app, we are considering to enable collaborative online editing. It is a graphic application heavily relying on javascript for creating mind-map-like structures.

The first obvious candidate is to use websockets.

Users come to the site to create those maps. I have looked at [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) which seems to start an own process, but

```
 EventMachine.run {

         EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 9876) do |ws|
```

it seems there is not much of context information there; people may be editing different maps at the same time!
So my current guess is to

- for every map being edited on, a new WebSocket server is started on a
  different port
- as this would entail control of the WebSocket
  life-cycle, I was thinking to spawn a `Thread` for every such `WebSocket` server:

  #on map create/edit:
         Thread.new do
             EventMachine.run {

  ```
           EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 9876) do |ws|
         ....
     end
  ```

What do people think on this approach? Is this reasonable? Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Will Git (or variant) not work for your project?  I know it's more of an offline option but is robust and well documented.

Comment: N1tr0, I am not sure I understand your commment...Git??? How does that play together with a WebSocket?

Comment: Git would be the alternative to WebSocket.  Git just allows collaborative development and handles conflicts and versioning, etc.  I might not be clear as to what you are trying to do and may be way off-base.

Comment: So, I'm not really familiar with WebSockets so I read the info a the GitHub link you provided.  I see what the technology is for but not sure how it could be applied to what you are doing.  Sorry I can't be of more help.